# IMAP não mostra email do remetente

Tags: php, imap

Estou fazendo um codigo para ler emails pelo IMAP, só que estou encontrando um problema para mostrar o email do remetente. ao invés de mostrar o email ele esta mostrando o nome. já tentei outras funções mais também não funcionaram  coloquei o

```
'remetente:  '.$header->fromaddress;.
```

mais não funciona.

Alguém saberia o motivo para este erro ?

abaixo segue o exemplo

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$status = imap_status($inbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", SA_ALL);
if ($status) {
echo "Total Messages:   " . $status->messages    . "<br />\n";
echo "Recentes:     " .  $status->recent      . "<br />\n";
echo "Não Lidas:     " . $nlidas = $status->unseen      . "<br />\n";
echo "Proximo Id:    " . $status->uidnext     . "<br />\n";
echo "Vizualizações:" . $status->uidvalidity . "<br />\n";
} else {
echo "imap_status failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
}
echo '<hr>';

   $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
   if($emails) {
   $output = '';
   rsort($emails);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,"1.1");
    $header = imap_header($inbox,$email_number,"1");

    echo  'Id: '. $id = $overview[0]->uid;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Assunto: '. $assunto = iconv_mime_decode($overview[0]->subject);
    echo '<br>';
    echo  'De: '. $de =$overview[0]->from;
    echo '<br>';
    echo  'Para: '. $para =$overview[0]->to;
    echo '<br>';
    echo  'Data:'. $data =$overview[0]->date;
    echo '<br>';
    echo  'remetente:  '.$header->fromaddress;
    echo '<br>';

      if (++$i == 10) break;
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    }

    } 

    imap_close($inbox);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, subistitui este código:

```
echo  'De: '. $de =$overview[0]->from;
echo '<br>';
```

por este código:

```
echo  'De: '. $de =$overview[0]->from;
$e=$header->from[0];
echo '['.$e->mailbox.'@'.$e->host.']';
echo '<br>';
```

Pois o `$overview->from;` só contem o nome inteligivel, não o e-mail do remetente. Caso queira verificar tudo o que cada objeto retornado possui, use: `print_r($objeto);` ou `print_r($overview[0]->from);` que o PHP imprime um array com todas as propriedades que cada objeto, array ou variável possui.